# Grow div height to fit the content inside

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flask, jquery-select2

I am trying to use [select2-bootstrap-theme](https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.3.html) in a `flask` web app. I am rendering an HTML template that uses **select2-bootstrap-theme**. If I directly open that `.html` file. Everything shows as it should but when I access the page with the flask app running, it destroys the format.

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/css/select2-bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#multiple").select2({ 
            maximumSelectionLength: 5,
            placeholder: "Click to select GW IDs",
            theme: "bootstrap"
            });
        })
</script>    
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
  <div class="container">
<form method="POST" action="" class="login100-form">
    <h1 align="center" style="font-variant: small-caps">Bank Portal System</h1><br>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="multiple" class="control-label">GW ID(s)</label>
        <select id="multiple" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple>
            <optgroup label="Category 1">
                <option>Value 1</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Category 2">
                <option>Value 1</option>
                <option>Value 2</option>
                <option>Value 3</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="default" class="control-label">From Date</label>
        <input id="default" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="default" class="control-label">To Date</label>
        <input id="default" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder text">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is what `main.html` shows when directly opened and this is exactly what I expect when I access the page with the app running.
[image]

And this is what it shows when accessed by the app.[image]

Comment: Appears the `<select id="multiple" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple>` element doesn't fit, hence scrolls. Check its `overflow` value.

Answer (score 0):

**Why did this happen**

The main reason why the components don't render properly because the dependencies are not loaded or injected to the DOM.

**How to fix the problem**

Make sure all the dependencies/utilities are properly loaded because these components work/function with help of their respective .js and .css files.

The problem in the code you've mention, I find that Jquery is not loaded properly.
you can just resolve it using a Jquery from CDN.

Example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to serve the Jquery file locally, please make sure the path specified is correct.